# Passing filename and file content arguments to perl script with GNU parallel

Tags: perl, awk, arguments, gnu-parallel

I am trying to parallelise the use of a perl script.  The input and output arguments for the perl script take the filenames from a directory.  This is straightforward with gnu parallel.

```
ls dir | parallel script.pl --input {} --output {.}.out
```

However, an additional argument in the script requires that I get the value of the first row and last row, second column, from each file... something like

```
ls dir | parallel script.pl --input {} --output {.}.out --otherargs range:{1}-{2}
```

where the {1} and {2} are derived from a previous/simultaneous use of awk or sed to get these values with, for example

```
awk 'NR==1 {print $2}; END {print $2}'
```

But where do I put (how can I put) this awk like step in the "workflow" to allow the perl script to use it?

Looking at

[Change text in argument for xargs (or GNU Parallel)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9688659/change-text-in-argument-for-xargs-or-gnu-parallel)

would the right approach simply be to do this?

```
ls | parallel script.pl --input {} --output {.}.out --otherargs range:{1}-{2} :::: <(awk 'NR==1 {print $2}) <(awk 'END {print $2})
```

Thank you.

Comment: Where would `awk 'NR==1 {print $2}'` take its input? From `ls` as well?

Comment: Yes, that's the idea.  script.pl and awk both take input from the file list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not really clear what you want. If this is not, then give us a full example of input and the wanted output.

```
ls | parallel script.pl --input {3} --output {3.}.out --otherargs range:{1}-{2} :::: <(ls | awk 'NR==1 {print $2}') <(ls | awk 'END {print $2}') -
```

or:

```
parallel script.pl --input {3} --output {3.}.out --otherargs range:{1}-{2} :::: <(ls | awk 'NR==1 {print $2}') <(ls | awk 'END {print $2}') <(ls)
```

Walk through the tutorial http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html Your command line will love you for it.

Comment: Ole - thank you.  That's exactly what I was thinking of. So {3} is the filename from the first ls call and then 1 and 2 are made from the <() syntax in GNU parallel?  Is the dash on the end needed?

Comment: The - at the end refers to stdin (i.e. the stuff before the | ). Answer updated with alternative.

Comment: @beckerhopper I have a made a note in our conversation about how this could be inefficient. And as expected calling `ls` thrice is needed for that one line command. I'm not sure how you could prefer this solution.

Answer (score 1):

This could be the solution you need:

```
#!/bin/bash
readarray -t LIST < <(ls)
FIRST=${LIST[0]}; LAST=${LIST[@]:(-1)}
printf '%s\n' "${LIST[@]}" | parallel script.pl --input {} --output {.}.out --otherargs "range:${FIRST}-${LAST}"
```

Run it as `bash script.sh`. And perhaps you need to run sort? `<(ls | sort)`. I think the concept will already follow even if you have a different source for `$FIRST` and `$LAST`.

A similar concept using a temporary file:

```
ls > temp
FIRST=$(awk 'NR==1 {print $2}' temp)
LAST=$(awk 'END {print $2}' temp}
parallel script.pl --input {} --output {.}.out --otherargs "range:${FIRST}-${LAST}" < temp
```

Also I think this is what you you really need with your Awk commands:

```
{read -r FIRST; read -r LAST;} < <(awk 'NR==1{print $2;next}{t=$2};END{print t}' temp)
```

Comment: I see what you are saying, but doesn't this make the acquisition of the first and last data a serial process and only the call to script.pl parallel?

Comment: @beckerhopper I don't really comprehend what you mean, but would you have a different result with that? You should also note that you can't read input twice, so you can't have multiple processes (parallel, awk, awk) reading a single output (ls). You have to store the output somewhere first like on a buffer (an array this case), and get your parameters accordingly.

Comment: If you want you can call `ls` twice, or thrice for every process but that would be just the same. Storing its output first on a buffer would be more efficient. And who knows that the output may already be different after the second or the third time.

Comment: The concept of using `tee` and the likes to duplicate output is just the same. Internally it would still store the input to a buffer before sending it to another two or more processes.

Comment: Good ideas.  I have answered this myself but can't post it yet (reputation too low).  bash script to collect relevant data and pass it to perl script.  Run bash script in GNU parallel.  Full details to come.

Answer (score 0):

My own solution was a bash script, passed to GNU paralle, but Ole's above is more elegant (a GNU parallel one liner).....  the bash script that collects the relevant variables and passes them to the perl script.  Run this script in GNU parallel.

Here is the bash script

```
#!/bin/bash
sample=$1
describer=$(echo ${sample} | sed 's/.sync//') # removes .sync suffix
a=($(awk 'NR==1 {print $2}' ${sample}))
b=($(awk 'END {print $2}' ${sample}))

perl script.pl --input ${describer}.sync --output ${describer}.genepop  
--argument scaffold_1:$a-$b
```

Followed by

```
ls | parallel bash bash.script.sh
```

This makes the collection of the variables from the file part and parcel of a files analysis.

Thanks for the motivating insight konsolebox.  I should have paid attention to my own old post too.

[Storing text and numeric variable from file to use in perl script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17449370/storing-text-and-numeric-variable-from-file-to-use-in-perl-script)